# Saripaar v2 validation (Upon validation failure, flow continues)

Tags: android, validation, saripaar

I am trying to use this neat validation framework but I hit the wall with this issue:

While doing the validation on a button click,I can see the fields being flagged but instead of aborting the execution, the flow continues.
Is there a way to just stop the execution on a validation error?

```
calculateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        validator.validate(); // if validate fails, flow should not continue
    }
}
```

It would have been easier to make the validate method boolean so you can make your own decision right?

Comment: Have you tried reading the [README](https://github.com/ragunathjawahar/android-saripaar)?

Answer (score 0):

There are two validation modes `BURST` and `IMMEDIATE`. Use `Mode.IMMEDIATE` to stop validation when there's a failure. You can set the mode using `validator.setValidationMode(Mode.IMMEDIATE)` to achieve the desired result.

Comment: What @kouami is trying to say is that once the validation fails, we iterate all errors and display them. What happens after that? How to not do the further steps when validation fails?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Ragunath but unfortunately your solution didn't solve my issues.
The flow doesn't abort when there is a validation failure. I can see the validation failures briefly and then the flow goes to the next fragment.